# How in Microsoft Word via styles can I highlight text only and not the entire line / paragraph

Tags: microsoft-word

I can do what I am asking about manually by first selecting the word and then clicking the Text Highlight Color button.

I am using Microsoft Word 2007.

I want this:
[image]
and not this:
[image]

**More Info** (though I doubt there is a solution to what I am asking about):

I am interested in doing this for an outline / Multilevel list--to be exact. For a particular level, let's say the 2nd level of the outline, I want the text to automatically be highlighted. I can only get the entire line and not the text only to be automatically highlighted every time the outline has a 2nd level. With text formatting options, like bold or underline, I don't have to select the text first. I was hoping that highlighting the text would work in the same way.

Comment: Do you mean exclude the spaces?

Comment: What?! Highlight text / background color on text / the way the background of text on a physical paper would look after you have highlighted words with a highlighter.

Comment: I'm not getting what you mean in the title about highlighting just the text and not the entire line.  Do you mean just a selected range of text?  And how does that tie back to styles (are you talking about applying a style to a selection or specific words via a rule)?  How is what you describe in your comment different from how Word works by default?  Any chance of adding a screenshot that illustrates what you're referring to?

Comment: I voted to reopen because what you are looking for is now clear.  However, you will still need to select the text.  After that you can do what you want by clicking the highlight button.  What is the value of trying to accomplish the same result using a style?

Comment: @fixer1234: I guess Rolo wants to just click somewhere in the paragraph and apply the style, and get all the text in the paragraph (but not all the space margin-to-margin) highlighted. Rolo: please confirm (and maybe edit the question to clarify) -- is that what you want, and are you looking to do this with a _paragraph_ format?

Comment: @Scott: I have added more info in the original question.

Comment: I'm looking for this answer too (for Word 2021).